# Find the sum of series bellow

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$(n^2+n)*{3}^{n-1}\over4^n$$
I've tried to break into 3 parts: $$({n^2\over4^n} + {n\over4^n}) * {3^n\over3*4^n}$$  but I don't know how to find the sum of $$n^2\over4^n$$

Comment: Is this an infinite or partial sum?

Comment: Okay, I have posted an explanation on how to solve your problem.

Comment: If you found one of these two answers to be a helpful answer to your question, you should accept one of them. :)

Answer (score 1):

By the formula for the sum of a geometric series,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n=\frac{1}{1-a}$$
for $|a| \lt 1$. Then we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty na^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(a-1)^2}$$
by differentiating both sides with respect to $a$. Then, if we multiply by $a$, we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty na^n=\frac{a}{(1-a)^2}$$
and, by differentiating again,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2a^{n-1}=\frac{a+1}{(1-a)^3}$$
and, when we multiply both sides again by $a$, we get
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2a^n=\frac{a^2+a}{(1-a)^3}$$
You should be able to plug $a=\frac{1}{4}$ directly into this formula to get your answer. If you have any questions, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For $|x|<1$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$ we have

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k$$

What happens to the relation above when you consider $f'(x)$ or $f''(x)$?